# Dynamic SQL query to list all master table's data

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have **N** numbers of Master tables in my database. To see all the data in the master tables, currently I'm writing `SELECT` query for each table. So I like to write a sql query to list all my master table's data in my database.

Since we are using a same standard for all master tables, so all the master tables are ending with the suffix `Master` only. Like `RoleMaster`, `UserMaster`, `UserRoleMaster`, `OfficeMaster`, `PincodeMaster` and many.

**What I have tried:**

The below query, returns the `SELECT` query for all master table.

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' + name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U' AND name LIKE '%Master'
```

It returns

```
SELECT * FROM RoleMaster
SELECT * FROM UserMaster
SELECT * FROM UserRoleMaster
SELECT * FROM OfficeMaster
SELECT * FROM PincodeMaster
...
...
```

Executing the below query always returns one table's data only. The `PRINT` statement returns `SELECT * FROM RoleMaster` only.

```
DECLARE @DynamicSql AS VARCHAR (MAX) = '';
SELECT @DynamicSql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U' AND name LIKE '%Master'  
PRINT @DynamicSql
EXEC (@DynamicSql)
```

What is the issue, what I missed here, why its not list all master table's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to add the `@DynamicSql` variable before start of the dynamic query, like `SELECT @DynamicSql = @DynamicSql + '`
- After `QUOTENAME(T.name)` you need to add a delimiter `+ '; '` to split the each line.

So the below query will works in your case:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSql AS NVARCHAR (MAX) = '';

SELECT @DynamicSql = @DynamicSql + 
        'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(S.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.name) + '; ' 
FROM sys.objects T
JOIN sys.schemas S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
WHERE T.[type] = 'U' AND T.name LIKE '%Master' 

--PRINT @DynamicSql
EXEC (@DynamicSql)
```

**Edit**: Based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720170/delete-all-tables-in-sql-server-database-except-few/38720685#comment64818387_38720685), I have updated the answer.