# Delete all tables in SQL Server database except few

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have around 50+ table in my database now what I want is drop all the tables in database except few.

now what I know is `sys.tables` is a table that list all tables so initially I ran a query like this

```
delete from sys.tables where name like '%DynamicSurgery' (or any other condition)
```

thinking that it might work. But as I expected it throws an error as

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

Please tell me if there is a way to delete multiples in SQL Server?

Comment: Test and development site? Have a script to re-create the database. Start all over when needed.

Comment: You can write a cursor to iterate through sys.tables, where you build up `drop table` statements and execute them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use dynamic query to `DROP` the required tables:

```
DECLARE @ExecSQL AS NVARCHAR (MAX) = '';

SELECT @ExecSQL = @ExecSQL + 
    'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(S.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.name) + '; ' 
FROM sys.tables T
JOIN sys.schemas S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
WHERE T.name LIKE '%DynamicSurgery'

--PRINT @ExecSQL
EXEC (@ExecSQL)
```

Comment: You *must* declare the variable as `NVARCHAR` because the table names may contain Unicode characters. You *should* make the `@ExecSQL` of length `(MAX)` because you do not know the number of tables (hence the length of the SQL). And you *should* use 2 part names `QUOTENAME(schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name)` because tables may belong to different schemas. And you *must* reference system tables and column by they correct names, **including case**, your example would fail on a case sensitive collation DB.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: Thanks for notifying. The said points are corrected.

Comment: Nice simple clean template for this type of problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
            EXEC sys.sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';

            EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF OBJECT_ID(''?'') NOT IN (
                  ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[Table1]''),0),
                  ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[Table2]''),0)
                  )
            DELETE FROM ?';

            EXEC sys.sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';
```

Answer (score -6):

1. select the table by clicking on it
2. press the delete button and hit enter.
   Take note : if there is any dependencies(Foreign Key), the table will not be deleted